# Install graph-tool on Mac OS, graph drawing issue

Tags: macos, python-3.6, cairo

In the end, created an `env` to install `graph-tool` thru the channel `vgauthier`.

Thinking by now that I might have as well used earlier version of python or installed a whole new python latest version just for this.

But as it is all part of the learning process to creating dev. env.. (at the same time worrying my Mac has too many installations with much too interlinked dependencies)

Someone kindly let me know if this rings any bell or got any suggestion:
`Incompatible library version` states that `_cairo.cpython-36m-darwin.so` requires later version of `libcairo.2.dylib`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors could have been from:

1. having on `.condarc` file, wrong priorities btw channels, so having trouble finding the right files
   (modified to the order of `conda-forge` > `~dir/vgauthier` > `default`
2. my having given up on installing `pygobject` after googling it is not supported on Mac OS (which was apparently wrong or I just wasnt searching well)

**Solution** to easy setup of `graph-tool` for `conda`-installed python users:

- Get the benefit of GUI (seriously a god option) ->

https://medium.com/@ronie/installing-graph-tool-for-python-3-on-anaconda-3f76d9004979

- To still continue with command line (still get the idea from GUI)
  `conda install -c pkgw-forge gtk3`
  `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/fallen pygobject`
  (if there are `cairo` blah blah missing, look up setup directions for `igraph` which has more information and help, having been an older library)

Do these before installing `graph-tool`, which Im still wondering why I cannot remove from the system though. ;)

For others, https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#compiler-choice-in-macos-x